# can not find osgi.enroute.iot.pi.provider dependency

Tags: raspberry-pi, osgi, iot, enroute

I am trying to do this tutorial

http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_iot/120-exploring.html

but I have got a problem with:

```
osgi.enroute.iot.pi.provider
```

package is not find so I can resolve bndrun dependencies:

```
Unable to resolve <<INITIAL>> version=null:
   missing requirement osgi.enroute.iot.pi.provider
```

and when I try with

```
osgi.enroute.iot.pi.command
```

dependencies not found:

```
Unable to resolve <<INITIAL>> version=null:
   missing requirement enroute.iot.raspberry.application  
->  Unable to resolve enroute.iot.raspberry.application version=1.0.0.201611270001:
   missing requirement com.pi4j.system]
```

I manually dowload and add pi4j in my project build path so I haven't no more eclipse problem but I fell that it is not a good solution for osgi and it not run on my remote raspberry ssh console...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Daghan from the osgi mailing list who provide a solution:

> "osgi.enroute.iot.pi.provider" is no longer a part of enroute distro. Please remove the manually downloaded pi4j from your project and do the following:
>
> 1- open cnf>central.xml
>
> 2- Add the following

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osgi/osgi.enroute.iot.pi.provider -->
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>osgi.enroute.iot.pi.provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This solve my problem but the include pi4j dependency isn't up to date for raspberry so I prefer add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and everything works like a charm now!